# Adding class on li and a on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm adding a class on li and a tags. But when I add class on "a" tag the class I add does not work. But the class I add on the li tag does work.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.active{
background: red; //This will be an image file. for simplicity I just use color
}

.current{
color:blue;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function() {

$("#navigation li").click(function() {

$("#navigation .active").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");

});

$("#navigation a").click(function() {

$("#navigation .current").removeClass("current");
$(this).addClass("current");

});
});
```

The class .active is working but the class .current does not.

Comment: I dont think there is any error. See this - http://jsfiddle.net/cTETF/1/

Comment: Hmm. I'll just double check my code.

Comment: Well I got it working. adding !important to the current class fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in this example. ( I had to take away the href out of the links so that I could see the css change)

**Html**

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a>Home</a></li>
  <li><a>About</a></li>
  <li><a>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.active{
 background: red; //This will be an image file. for simplicity I just use color
}

.current{
  color:orange;
}

li {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

**jQuery**

`No change.`

http://jsfiddle.net/cTETF/

**Update**

You don't have to add the classes in two separate click events.. It would probably be better to do it in the same click event.

```
$(function() {

$("#navigation li").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#navigation .active").removeClass("active");
   $("#navigation .current").removeClass("current");
   $(this).addClass("active");
   $(this).find("a").addClass("current");
});

});
```

Comment: Hmmm. That's weird I'm using the exact code and current is not being applied.

Comment: I'm not sure what behavior your looking for.. You may want to add and remove the class for both elements no matter what is clicked.  For example if you look at my fiddle if you click the `li` element and not the `a` only the li element gets changed.

Comment: I'll make a fiddle that demonstrates that.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But i got it working. Problem is when I click the color changes to the one i set. It is overwritten in my css file. So I added color: red !important; and that fix the problem. Anyway I'll accept this as answer for helping me out. Thanks.